# Drop Down bar float's right/down. The whole grid moves ones hovers over it

Tags: html, css

The element is not aligning with other elements. I can't understand why. The other issues if I hover over the link the grid shakes (moves). Should the grid be somehow stabilized?

```css
.main-content {
  grid-area: main;
}

.menu {
  grid-area: menu;
  padding-right: 5%;
}

.menu * {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul {
  text-align: right;
}

.menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  padding: 15px;
}

.grid-main div {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.grid-main {
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr, 1fr, 8fr, 1fr, 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "logo menu menu menu signin" ". main main signup signup" ". main main signup signup" ". main main signup signup";
}

And the drop down list is as styled as : .language {
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.language:hover .dropdown-menu {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#features">What's Special?</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#screenshot">Opportunities</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Cost's</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#team">Vacancies</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#contact"> Help &amp; Support </a>
    </li>
    <li class="language ">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"> </span> English</a>
      <section class="dropdown-menu ">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#fr">
          <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-fr"> </span> French</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#it">
          <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-it"> </span> Italian</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#ru">
          <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ru"> </span> Russian</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#de">
          <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-de"> </span> Deutch</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#de">
          <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cz"> </span> Česká republika</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="../lv/index.html">
          <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-lv"> </span> Latviešu</a>
      </section>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I expect all to be aligned in one row with the least code possible.

Currently it is sliding outside the grid. And I thought this should not be possible with the grid used below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6OGG.png)

Comment: try to fix pixels of  padding up and down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added  `right: 20px;` to  `.language:hover .dropdown-menu`

```css
.main-content {
  grid-area: main;
}

.menu {
  grid-area: menu;
  padding-right: 5%;
}

.menu * {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul {
  text-align: right;
}

.menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  padding: 15px;
}

.grid-main div {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.grid-main {
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr, 1fr, 8fr, 1fr, 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "logo menu menu menu signin" ". main main signup signup" ". main main signup signup" ". main main signup signup";
}

And the drop down list is as styled as: .language {
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.language:hover .dropdown-menu {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#features">What's Special?</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#screenshot">Opportunities</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Cost's</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#team">Vacancies</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#contact"> Help &amp; Support </a>
    </li>
    <li class="language ">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"> </span> English</a>
      <section class="dropdown-menu ">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#fr">
          <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-fr"> </span> French</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#it">
          <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-it"> </span> Italian</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#ru">
          <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ru"> </span> Russian</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#de">
          <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-de"> </span> Deutch</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#de">
          <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cz"> </span> Česká republika</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="../lv/index.html">
          <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-lv"> </span> Latviešu</a>
      </section>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't fixing the isssue. For some reason the whole page is moving and jumping around once I press on link.

Comment: but it is not happening in the code that you have put.

Comment: Could be other element's which have been 'linked to the data'. I have solved this though by all of your advise. Now need to understand how to close this question here! :D

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will resolve the issue, that you are dealing with. and I am adding the css only that which is changed.

```
.language {
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;

    min-width: 160px;

    right: 0;
    max-width: 160px;
    height: 100%;
}
 .menu ul {
    position:relative;
}
```

Below is the link for the [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/vss_at_kavayah/pen/KKPxqQK)

Comment: Actually none of these worked. At first glimpse it worked, but that was because the screen was re-sized to a smaller one. I will see if I can create anything, that does not break the grid. After this I will post a more concrete question as I am new to all of this! HTML CSS, and stack overflow as well :)

Answer (score 0):

This actually solved my issue. The fix was still due to the positioning. The issue which happened was because other element's were not positioned correctly and thus the web page grid was blinking on hovers.

```
   .language {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        /*Needs to be relative, as this then will set the dropdown-menu to absolute and will display the content correctly */
    }

    .dropdown-menu {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        /*Absolute is needed so that this is displayed correctly under the English choise. */
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 175px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-menu a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: left;
        display: block;
    }

.dropdown-menu a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.language:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```